# PhoneGap 3 Android deploy/install error

Tags: android, cordova

I've just installed PhoneGap on my Windows 8 machine.
When I try to deploy my app on an emulated Android, it throws the following:

```
D:\>phonegap install android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
   [error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project.Buildfile: D:\app\platforms\andro
id\build.xml
```

Any idea what that error means?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

You need to create a new Environment Variable called "ANDROID_HOME".

The value for this variable is your sdk location. In my case, I put: "C:\Users\Jesualdo\Desktop\sdk\sdk\tools".

And there is an important point:

First, you need to execute the emulator. Then you can install your app.

Check this link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The Android ADB path has changed from android-sdk\tools to android-sdk\platform-tools in the recent SDK version. This was the problem. It couldn't find ADB. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: how to fix this path change?

Comment: Include both `android-sdk\tools` and `android-sdk\platform-tools` in the PATH